# OpenCV : How to set delay time for each frame when writing video

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, video

I'm a beginner with OpenCV.
Can you show me how to set delay time for each frame, I want each frame of video will show in n seconds. (user'll input value of n)
I'm using Windows 7 64-bit  Visual Studio 2010 and opencv 2.4.5
thank.

Answer (score 1):

The fps parameter of VideoWriter enable you to do that.
[OpenCV Documentation : VideoWriter](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videowriter-videowriter)

Fps is the number of image per second so if you want to have 1 photo per n seconds :
- 1 image per second : fps = 1
- 1 image per 2 seconds : fps = 0.5
- 1 image per 3 seconds : fps = 1/3
- 1 image per n seconds : fps = 1/n